# Can not generate thumbnail from url video in ios 13

Tags: swift, swift4

I am using the below code to generate a frame from a video URL. This code was working fine for sometime before. right now it's not working. it is throwing an error that it can not decode and the file may be damaged. can someone help with this?

```
func previewImageFromVideo(url: NSURL) -> UIImage? {
        let url = url as URL
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let cache = URLCache.shared

        if
            let cachedResponse = cache.cachedResponse(for: request),
            let image = UIImage(data: cachedResponse.data)
        {
            return image
        }

        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
        let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        imageGenerator.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 120)

        var time = asset.duration
        time.value = min(time.value, 2)

        var image: UIImage?

        do {
            let cgImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
            image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        } catch { }

        if
            let image = image,
            let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image),
            let response = HTTPURLResponse(url: url, statusCode: 200, httpVersion: nil, headerFields: nil)
        {
            let cachedResponse = CachedURLResponse(response: response, data: data)

            cache.storeCachedResponse(cachedResponse, for: request)
        }

        return image
    }
```

This code throws an error while capturing a frame from the URL video. It says the file might be damaged.

Comment: Which Video URL you use and got error please share URL.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on Playground, it works perfectly. The file could be damaged as the error message says.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
container.addSubview(imageView)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func previewImageFromVideo(url: NSURL) -> UIImage? {
    let url = url as URL
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let cache = URLCache.shared

    if
        let cachedResponse = cache.cachedResponse(for: request),
        let image = UIImage(data: cachedResponse.data)
    {
        return image
    }

    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    imageGenerator.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 120)

    var time = asset.duration
    time.value = min(time.value, 2)

    var image: UIImage?

    do {
        let cgImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    } catch { }

    if
        let image = image,
        let data = image.pngData(),
        let response = HTTPURLResponse(url: url, statusCode: 200, httpVersion: nil, headerFields: nil)
    {
        let cachedResponse = CachedURLResponse(response: response, data: data)

        cache.storeCachedResponse(cachedResponse, for: request)
    }

    return image
}

imageView.image = previewImageFromVideo(url: NSURL(string: "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to Suh's answer, and I have used it on the background thread so that while generating the thumbnail our UI won't get blocked.

```
 func createVideoThumbnail( url: String?,  completion: @escaping ((_ image: UIImage?)->Void)) {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: url ?? "") else { return }
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        
        let url = url as URL
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let cache = URLCache.shared
        
        if
            let cachedResponse = cache.cachedResponse(for: request),
            let image = UIImage(data: cachedResponse.data)
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(image)
            }
        }
        
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
        let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        
        var time = asset.duration
        time.value = min(time.value, 2)
        
        var image: UIImage?
        
        do {
            let cgImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
            image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        } catch { DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(nil)
        } }
        
        if
            let image = image,
            let data = image.pngData(),
            let response = HTTPURLResponse(url: url, statusCode: 200, httpVersion: nil, headerFields: nil)
        {
            let cachedResponse = CachedURLResponse(response: response, data: data)
            
            cache.storeCachedResponse(cachedResponse, for: request)
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(image)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
      createVideoThumbnail(url: data.url ?? "") { [weak self] (img) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            if let image = img {
                strongSelf.mediaImg.image = image
            }
        }
```